# Apache loads other old website after rebooting

Tags: apache, raspberry-pi, backup, restore

I've got a little problem: Whenever I restart my Raspyberry Pi B, an old version of my website gets loaded.

Before the restart, I changed whole files and deleted some. But even the deleted files get restored after rebooting the rapsberry.

It's really annoying if my new website gets thrown away ...

I don't know if it's the Apache service or something different.

Anyone knows a solution for that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: so your browser shows the new website before reboot and the old one after? Have you checked if the files are changed back after the reboot? Do you have your raspi connected to a NTP?

Comment: Correct. My browser shows the correct new one before I reboot and after, it shows the website from about 2 days ago. And yes, the old files are restored and the new files deleted. No, I haven't connect the rapsy to anything.

Comment: hm, have no scenario here where I could try to reproduce it so we'll have to go through it theoretically. The place where the website is stored on the raspi, may that be somehow linked to a temp ramdisk-like filesystem that is not synced back to the sdcard? Do you expect the website files on sdcard or on an usb disk? After updating the files but before rebooting, can you change to the directory where you have updated the files and do a `df -m .` so we see on what filesystem they landed?

Comment: Ok, here's the output of df -m . (I put the files in the usual directrory, /var/www):                                                       root@Dominik-Pi:~# df -m .
/dev/root          29596    3980     24361   15%   /

Comment: so that looks like a 30GB filesystem, probably on the sdcard - do you observe the effect of rolled-back files also on other places than just /var/www, maybe in /home ? As you see, I'm completely clueless what goes on -might be anything down to a broken sdcard

Comment: This exact thing has happened to me. Raspberry Pi B+/Apache. Site was down, briefly showed a cert error, said cert expired 33 days ago (using certbot for HTTPS, supposed to auto renew). Did a reboot, checked the cert and it said it was up to date, but getting old site. Deleted the website files, copied them back over and everything seems okay. Time will tell.